# MySQL - SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://

Tags: java, mysql

I'm a programming noob so please be gentle with me ;_;

basically - I've created a MySQL Java database and I'm getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/StudentScores
```

Error doesn't show up during compilation only when I run it, fill in details and click "Add Student" (database stores student details of test scores)

here's the code

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try
    {
        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/StudentScores ";
        String username = "admin3";
        String password = "admin3";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String Query = "INSERT INTO STUDENT (NAME, DATEOFQUIZ, MEMORYSCORE, COMPREHENSIONSCORE, PROBLEMSOLVINGSCORE, AVERAGEPERCENTAGE) VALUES ('"+NameText.getText()+"','"+DateText.getValue()+"','"+MemoryScoreText.getText()+"','"+ComprehensionScoreText.getText()+"','"+ProblemSolvingScoreText.getText()+"', '"+AveragePercentageText.getText()+"')";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student Added");

        NameText.setText(null);
        DateText.setText("00/00/0000");
        MemoryScoreText.setText(null);
        ComprehensionScoreText.setText(null);
        ProblemSolvingScoreText.setText(null);
        AveragePercentageText.setText(null);

    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
    }
}
```

help me out? thanks :)

Comment: Derby (the driver your code is looking for) is not MySQL.

Comment: oh... what's the driver im looking for then :/

Comment: @z33 Please check answer

Comment: i cant find my stack trace - using netbeans IDE i clicked window -> debugging -> call stack and it's just an empty page

Comment: @z33 Please check answer

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to load the Derby driver, not the one for MySQL.  Your JDBC url should be

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/StudentScores
```

instead. If you still get the same exception after fixing that, then you need to ensure that the MySQL driver jar file is in your classpath.

Comment: didn't work and ah i see i need a driver... gonna find one now can you give a name of one? :)

Comment: thank you! so i connected that but now i get a different error : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications lin failure. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: Please post a new question with your current code and the complete stack trace.

Comment: @JimGarrison 
i cant find my stack trace - using netbeans IDE i clicked window -> debugging -> call stack and it's just an empty page...

Comment: It will be in your console output.  The Call Stack is for when you are actually executing your code and have stopped at a breakpoint.  After the program terminates the call stack is non-existent.

Comment: @JimGarrison it just says build successful

Comment: I've invited you to a chat session

Comment: @JimGarrison i finally found it X'D but i need 20 reps to chat :(

Comment: Oops.  Join a second SE site (such as [sf] or [su]) under the same login  to get a 100 bonus.

Comment: Sorry, there must be a minimum to get the bonus, or they've changed it since I last checked.  It's been a loooong time since I was at that point.  I suggest you look around and if possible answer some questions to gain some rep.  All you need is two upvotes.

Comment: On your original question: The stack trace will occur if there's an exception thrown when you RUN the program.  "Build Successful" is a build-time message, not a runtime message.

Comment: alright i'm gonna find things i can actually answer